# PHP dom getAttribute with HTML5 attributes

Tags: php, dom, html, attributes

How are we supposed to check the value for the following HTML5 attributes?

```
<input type="text" required />
```

Or this:

```
<video src="" autoplay></video>
```

This is the code I use:

```
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);    
$result = $xpath->query('//input');

foreach($result as $item) var_dump($item->getAttribute('required'));
```

The required attribute may or may not be set, the result stays the same:

```
string(0) ""
```

If getAttribute would return null instead of an empty string when the attribute is not defined it would make more sense.

I am aware we can use something like required="required" but I can't be sure that the attribute is in that form since the code that gets parse may differ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the rule is that if the attribute exists, then apply the action. So try `hasAttribute('required')`

Comment: Great! This seems to work correctly. Why did I overlook that function?

Answer (score 2):

try

```
$item['required']
```

instead of

```
$item->getAttribute('required')
```

Comment: $item is an object so we can't treat it like an array.

Comment: In php if you implement ArrayAccess then any object can be used as array . (Bassically __set , __get magic function ) simplexml is not exception to it